# I would like to know if there is a way with Hibernate to perform a programmatic configuration of ColumnTransformer ?

Tags: hibernate

I currently have a field annotated like this :

```
ColumnTransformer(
          read="AES_DECRYPT(C_first_name, 'yourkey')",
          write="AES_ENCRYPT(?, 'yourkey')")
public String getFirstName() {
   return firstName;
}
```

This is working properly with a Mysql database, but I need this configuration to be optional, because our application can use another database (HsqlDB) depending on start parameters. So what I need is a way to use a ColumnTransformer only when a specific start parameter is used (and no ColumnTransformer for HsqlDB, which cant use "AES_ENCRYPT")

Can someone help me with this ?

Comment: What means a `start parameter` ? a JVM arg ? a property in some property file ?

Comment: @ben65  a property in property file

Comment: Thank you for the AES_DECRYPT(C_first_name, 'yourkey').

Answer (score 8):

I had same problem, I want key to be configurable. The only solution i found for this item is to update annotation values at runtime. Yes, i know that this sounds awful, but as far as i know there is no other way.

Entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User implements Serializable {
    @Column(name = "password")
    @ColumnTransformer(read = "AES_DECRYPT(password, '${encryption.key}')", write = "AES_ENCRYPT(?, '${encryption.key}')")
    private String password;
}
```

I implemented class that replaces ${encryption.key} to the some other value (in my case loaded from Spring application context)

```
import org.hibernate.annotations.ColumnTransformer;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.Proxy;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

@Component(value = "transformerColumnKeyLoader")
public class TransformerColumnKeyLoader {

    public static final String KEY_ANNOTATION_PROPERTY = "${encryption.key}"; 

    @Value(value = "${secret.key}")
    private String key;

    @PostConstruct
    public void postConstruct() {
        setKey(User.class, "password");
    }

    private void setKey(Class<?> clazz, String columnName) {
        try {
            Field field = clazz.getDeclaredField(columnName);

            ColumnTransformer columnTransformer = field.getDeclaredAnnotation(ColumnTransformer.class);
            updateAnnotationValue(columnTransformer, "read");
            updateAnnotationValue(columnTransformer, "write");
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException | SecurityException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(
                    String.format("Encryption key cannot be loaded into %s,%s", clazz.getName(), columnName));
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private void updateAnnotationValue(Annotation annotation, String annotationProperty) {
        Object handler = Proxy.getInvocationHandler(annotation);
        Field merberValuesField;
        try {
            merberValuesField = handler.getClass().getDeclaredField("memberValues");
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException | SecurityException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
        merberValuesField.setAccessible(true);
        Map<String, Object> memberValues;
        try {
            memberValues = (Map<String, Object>) merberValuesField.get(handler);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
        Object oldValue = memberValues.get(annotationProperty);
        if (oldValue == null || oldValue.getClass() != String.class) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format(
                    "Annotation value should be String. Current value is of type: %s", oldValue.getClass().getName()));
        }

        String oldValueString = oldValue.toString();
        if (!oldValueString.contains(TransformerColumnKeyLoader.KEY_ANNOTATION_PROPERTY)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    String.format("Annotation value should be contain %s. Current value is : %s",
                            TransformerColumnKeyLoader.KEY_ANNOTATION_PROPERTY, oldValueString));
        }
        String newValueString = oldValueString.replace(TransformerColumnKeyLoader.KEY_ANNOTATION_PROPERTY, key);

        memberValues.put(annotationProperty, newValueString);
    }
}
```

This code should be run **before** creating EntityManager. In my case i used depends-on (for xml config or @DependsOn for java config).

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" depends-on="transformerColumnKeyLoader"> ... </bean>
```

Comment: I didn't have `entityManagerFactory` in my project, so I added depends-on to `sessionFactory`, and it seems to work as well.

Comment: How to do this for spring boot

Comment: @Palsri For Spring boot, don't make TransformerColumnKeyLoader a bean. Simply make an instance of it as a POJO before SpringApplication.run(), and call its postConstruct().

Comment: It worked. Good solution..

Answer (score 1):

The hibernate configuration is essentially static. It is not intended to be modified at runtime. But it can be done if you do it carefully.

Basically, the usual way to build a SessionFactory is by doing something like this:

```
  AnnotationConfiguration conf = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure();
  sessionFactory = conf.buildSessionFactory();
```

Most of the time this code is part a of framework (for instance, with Spring you must look into SessionFactoryBean to find it). So the first thing to do is indentify this portion of code and overriding the framework component doing it so that you get an access to the `conf` object BEFORE it is use to `buildSessionFactory()`.

Then you have to modify the AnnotationConfiguration to remove/add the data related to *optional* annotations:

```
  {
      ...
      AnnotationConfiguration conf = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure();
      if(FLAG_INDICATING_TO_REMOVE_SOME_ANNOTATION){
          manipulateHibernateConfig(conf);
      }
      sessionFactory = conf.buildSessionFactory();
      ...
  }

  private void manipulateHibernateConfig(AnnotationConfiguration conf){
      ...
     //this is the tricky part because lot of fields and setters are either
     //final or private so it requires reflection etc...

     //you must also be sure that those manipulation won't break the config !
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the @ColumnTransformer is complete load before Runtime, and you want to use @Value get key from  application.properties must meet the Runtime, so you will find when you embed the key in @ColumnTransformer will warning 'Attribute value must be constant'.
However, we can change another way, following is my solution:

1.Write an AES algorithm utils.

2.Override your entity class get/set method.

```
import static com.mysql.demo.utils.AesEncodeUtil.encrypt2Str;
import static com.mysql.demo.utils.AesEncodeUtil.decrypt2Str;
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
public class Employee {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;
private String name;
public void setName(String name) throws Exception {
    this.name = encrypt2Str(name, PRIVATE_KEY);
  }

public String getName() throws Exception {
    return decrypt2Str(name, PRIVATE_KEY);
  }
}
```

this is [my demo](https://github.com/linchuhao/sensitive-data-manage) in Github.

Answer (score 0):

Based on user3035947's answer:

```
@Component
public class RemoveAesFunction {



    @PostConstruct
    public void postConstruct() {
        setKey(MyEntity.class);
    }

    private void setKey(Class<?> clazz) {
        try {
            Field field = clazz.getDeclaredField("firstName");

            ColumnTransformer columnTransformer = field.getDeclaredAnnotation(ColumnTransformer.class);
            updateAnnotationValue(columnTransformer, "read","");
            updateAnnotationValue(columnTransformer, "write","?");
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException | SecurityException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private void updateAnnotationValue(Annotation annotation, String annotationProperty,String value) {
        Object handler = Proxy.getInvocationHandler(annotation);
        Field merberValuesField;
        try {
            merberValuesField = handler.getClass().getDeclaredField("memberValues");
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException | SecurityException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
        merberValuesField.setAccessible(true);
        Map<String, Object> memberValues;
        try {
            memberValues = (Map<String, Object>) merberValuesField.get(handler);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }

        memberValues.put(annotationProperty, value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did this this actually work for you? I see this class (RemoveAesFunction) being initialised and memberValues populated correctly as I would have expected, ie: to include my key from config 

BUT when actually saving the entity that has this annotation on it, it has not effect.

Comment: @Melissa Same here, did you manage to solve it?

Comment: @0x01Brain no I never did manage to get around this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also trying to override @ColumnTransformer annotation.
The component starts before the entity manager's inject but when I execute the query the field returns null as if the correct key is not passed.
If I insert the key directly into the annotation everything works.
The value is printed correctly before executing the query

**Entity Field**

```
@Column(name = "NAME")
@ColumnTransformer(read = "AES_DECRYPT(NAME, '${encryption.key}')")
private String name;
```

**Query Manager**

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<FooBar> query = builder.createQuery(FooBar.class);
Root<FooBar> root = query.from(FooBar.class);
query.select(root);
query.where(builder.and(builder.equal(root.get(FooBar_.id), id),
                builder.equal(root.get(FooBar_.STATUS), 0),
                builder.equal(root.get(FooBar_.REQUEST), true)));
Field field = FooBar.class.getDeclaredField("name");
ColumnTransformer oldAnnotation = field.getDeclaredAnnotation(ColumnTransformer.class);
LOGGER.debug("oldAnnotation = " + oldAnnotation.read());
entity = em.createQuery(query).getSingleResult();
```

**TransformerColumnKeyLoader**

```
@Component(value = "transformerColumnKeyLoader")
public class TransformerColumnKeyLoader {

public static final String KEY_ANNOTATION_PROPERTY = "${encryption.key}";

@Value(value = "${secret.key}")
private String key;

@PostConstruct
public void postConstruct() {
    setKey(FooBar.class, "name");
}

private void setKey(Class<?> clazz, String columnName) {
    try {
        Field field = clazz.getDeclaredField(columnName);

        ColumnTransformer columnTransformer = field.getDeclaredAnnotation(ColumnTransformer.class);
        updateAnnotationValue(columnTransformer, "read");
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException | SecurityException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(
                String.format("Encryption key cannot be loaded into %s,%s", clazz.getName(), columnName));
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private void updateAnnotationValue(Annotation annotation, String annotationProperty) {
    Object handler = Proxy.getInvocationHandler(annotation);
    Field merberValuesField;
    try {
        merberValuesField = handler.getClass().getDeclaredField("memberValues");
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException | SecurityException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(e);
    }
    merberValuesField.setAccessible(true);
    Map<String, Object> memberValues;
    try {
        memberValues = (Map<String, Object>) merberValuesField.get(handler);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(e);
    }
    Object oldValue = memberValues.get(annotationProperty);
    if (oldValue == null || oldValue.getClass() != String.class) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format(
                "Annotation value should be String. Current value is of type: %s", oldValue.getClass().getName()));
    }

    String oldValueString = oldValue.toString();
    if (!oldValueString.contains(TransformerColumnKeyLoader.KEY_ANNOTATION_PROPERTY)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                String.format("Annotation value should be contain %s. Current value is : %s",
                        TransformerColumnKeyLoader.KEY_ANNOTATION_PROPERTY, oldValueString));
    }
    String newValueString = oldValueString.replace(TransformerColumnKeyLoader.KEY_ANNOTATION_PROPERTY, key);

    memberValues.put(annotationProperty, newValueString);
    System.out.println(memberValues);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This approach mentioned by colleagues is very interesting. I would just add that use the application.properties or as an environment variable seems not to be the best approach once it is a kind of sensitive data and may vary for each customer your solution is consumed.

It would be interesting to encrypt data with a customer-specific key, so you would need to access the setKey() method from outside this class to redefine depending on your customer.