# Spring JPA ColumnTransformer to read value from application.properties file

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am using hibernate annotation **@ColumnTransformer** to make use of MySQL data encryption, however, I don't want (actually I can not) hard code the password into the code, instead, I want to load the password say from **application.properties** file, sample as below:

````
@NotBlank
@Column(name = "phone_numbers", columnDefinition = "LONGBLOB")
@ColumnTransformer(
        read="AES_DECRYPT(phone_numbers, '${mms.encryption.key}')",
        write="AES_ENCRYPT(?, '${mms.encryption.key}')")
private String phoneNumbers;```
````

The **mms.encryption.key** is an entry in **application.properties**

`mms.encryption.key=mypassword`

But seems this one won't work. What is the best way to do this?

I found a similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19541252/i-would-like-to-know-if-there-is-a-way-with-hibernate-to-perform-a-programmatic), but I am not sure if someone has a better solution in year 2018.

Comment: Did you get the better solution?