# Quarkus data encryption with hibernate @ColumnTransformer: how to read key from application.properties?

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, encryption, quarkus

I need encrypt/decrypt data with @ColumnTransformer (with Postgres DB) but I don't want an hardcoded key or store it in postgresql.conf.
I am able to get the key from application.properties with:

```
@ConfigProperty(name = "encryptionkey")
    String key;
```

Unfortunately I cannot use it in @ColumnTransformer annotation because it requires a constant string.
Moreover I cannot use @AttributeConverter because I need do queries with "like" and I've tried yet but it did not work.
I have followed also this discussion which uses reflection for update annotation value at runtime : [I would like to know if there is a way with Hibernate to perform a programmatic configuration of ColumnTransformer ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19541252/i-would-like-to-know-if-there-is-a-way-with-hibernate-to-perform-a-programmatic;) but it has not worked for me, infact I can replace the hardcoded key with "encryptionkey" when Quarkus starts but when I persists my entity, it has no effect.
Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.