# use Spring SPEL in entity class

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have declared a property in application.yml file

```
myapp:
  key: lasdfuiwfaskjgfahsgdfhasgdflwer8wezxnb612782rt
```

and in the configuration class

```
@Data
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "myapp")
public class ConfigurationHolder {

    public String key;
  
}
```

I want to use this key, value in an entity class in column transformer for encryption

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "test_user")
public class TestUser {

    @Column
    @ColumnTransformer(
            read = "cast(AES_DECRYPT(testKey, #{configurationHolder.key}) as char)",
            write = "AES_ENCRYPT(?, #{configurationHolder.key})"
    )
    private String testKey;
    
}
```

How can i verify that the value of key from the application.yml file is used for encryption and decryption for the column.

Answer (score 1):

There was a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19541252/i-would-like-to-know-if-there-is-a-way-with-hibernate-to-perform-a-programmatic).

The answerer recommends writing a custom Spring component that shall replace the annotation value in runtime via Reflection API. This is a dirty hack, but it can work.

I would suggest going for a [custom JPA Attribute Converter](https://thorben-janssen.com/how-to-use-jpa-type-converter-to/). You can use [`@Configurable`](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-inject-bean-into-unmanaged-objects) annotation to inject `@Value` in the unmanaged object.

```java
@Configurable
public class MyConverter extends implements AttributeConverter<String, String> {
    @Value("myapp.key")
    private String key;
}

...

@Entity
@Table(name = "test_user")
public class TestUser {

    @Column
    @Convert(converter = MyConverter.class)
    private String testKey;
    
}
```